# SQL Azure - query with row_number() executes slow if columns with nvarchar of big size are included

Tags: performance, azure, azure-sql-database, sqlperformance

I have the following query (generated by Entity Framework with standard paging. This is the inner query and I added the TOP 438 part):

```
SELECT TOP 438 [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
                  [Extent1].[MemberType] AS [MemberType], 
                  [Extent1].[FullName] AS [FullName], 
                  [Extent1].[Image] AS [Image], 
                  row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Extent1].[FullName] ASC) AS [row_number]
        FROM [dbo].[ShowMembers] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE 3 =  CAST( [Extent1].[MemberType] AS int)
```

ShowMembers table has about 11K rows, but only 438 with MemberType == 3. The 'Image' column is of type nvarchar(2000) that holds the URL to the image on a CDN. If I include this column in the query (only in SELECT part), the query chokes up somehow and generates result in a range between 2-30 seconds (it differs in different runs). If I comment out that column, query runs fast as expected. If I include the 'Image' column, but comment out the row_number column, query also runs fast as expected.

Obviously, I've been too liberal with the size of the URL, so I started playing around with the size. I found out that if I set the Image column to nvarchar(884), then the query runs fast as expected. If I set it up to 885 it's slow again. 
This is not bound to one column, but to the size of all columns in the SELECT statement. If I just increase the size by one, performance differences are obvious.

I am not a DB expert, so any advice is welcomed.

PS In local SQL Server 2012 Express there are no performance issues.

PPS Running the query with OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 438 ROWS ONLY (without the row_count column of course) is also slow.

Comment: I would suggest you take a look at the design behind Tables and Indexes in SQL Server to understand the difference. You've identified a threshold and a change that appears to have a positive impact.  Is there a specific programming question here such as "What is the maximum column size I should consider for my Image column?"  MSDN Info on Tables, etc: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189051.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Row_number has to sort all the rows to get you things in the order you want.  Adding a larger column into the result set implies that it all get sorted and thus is much slower/does more IO.  You can see this, btw, if you enable "set statistics io on" and "set statistics time on" in SSMS when debugging problems like this.  It will give you some insight into the number of IOs and other operations happening at runtime in the query:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-statistics-io-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

In terms of what you can do to make this query go faster, I encourage you to think about some things that may change the design of your database schema a bit.  First, consider whether you actually need the rows sorted in a specific order at all.  If you don't need things in order, it will be cheaper to iterate over them without the row_number (by a measurable amount).  So, if you just want to conceptually iterate over each entry once, you can do that by doing an order by something more static that is still monotonic such as the identity column.  Second, if you do need to have things in sorted order, then consider whether they are changing frequently/infrequently.  If it is infrequent, it may be possible to just compute and persist a column value into each row that has the relative order that you want (and update it each time you modify the table).  In this model, you could index the new column and then request things in that order (in the top-level order by in the query - row_number not needed).  If you do need things dynamically computed like you are doing and you need things in an exact order all the time, your final option is to move the URL to a second table and join with it after the row_number.  This will avoid the sort being "wide" in the computation of row_number.

Best of luck to you